# Using jQuery to obtain JSON from hardware on local network via IP/device.json

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having an issue obtaining json from a piece of hardware on a local network.

I can view the json code using this address in a browser:

http://192.168.1.103/device.json

I also saved the resulting text to a file device.json and placed it in the same directory as my test.php file.

This code works:

```
$.getJSON('device.json',function(data) {

        $.each(data.mainunit.sensors, function(i, sensor) {

        $("#results").append('<p>'+sensor.name+' = '+sensor.tc+'</p>');

        });
```

This doesn't work: (changing device.json to http://192.168.1.103/device.json)

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.103/device.json',function(data) {

        $.each(data.mainunit.sensors, function(i, sensor) {

        $("#results").append('<p>'+sensor.name+' = '+sensor.tc+'</p>');

        });
```

My guess is the code can't view the JSON file at the IP address.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really annoying how this stuff fails silently. Firebug has a 'Net' tab that can show http headers and responses for ajax requests so that might give you some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your JSON with some callback function. If your `device.json` looks like that:

```
{ "a" : true, "b" : false }
```

Modify it to be [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)-compliant:

```
my_wrapper() { { "a" : true, "b" : false } }
```

How to request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://192.168.1.103/device.json",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "my_wrapper",
  success: function(data) {
     //Handle data
  }
}
```

Didn't test the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to contact the device manufacturer and see if they can add that.  Thanks.

Comment: The manufacturer is releasing a patch to provide JSONP.  Thanks for the request sample.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a same origin policy violation:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Under "Additional Notes" on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: You could proxy the request via the web server, either using mod_proxy or if it's low volume (which I suspect it is) you could write up a server side script to receive your json request, hit the device (e.g using curl) and then pipe out the response.

Comment: Can this be resolved using a ScriptTagProxy?  If so would I have read/write access to the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

2. Use JSONP as [per @floatless suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086691/using-jquery-to-obtain-json-from-hardware-on-local-network-via-ip-device-json/7086785#7086785).
3. Ask the device manufacturer to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header ([more about it at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control)).
4. Proxy requests to your device while adding either JSONP wrapping or the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

The last one is that you can do right away.